# bug in redux template where do I write to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a very small problem, but my OCD can not let it go.
if we were to install redux react template with npx (npx create-react-app my-app --template redux) we could find that **incrementIfOdd** reducer works only for positive numbers.

```
export const incrementIfOdd = (amount) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const currentValue = selectCount(getState());
  if (currentValue % 2 === 1) {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }
};
```

but we could replace (currentValue % 2 === 1) with (currentValue % 2 !== 0) and it would work perfectly.

```
export const incrementIfOdd = (amount) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const currentValue = selectCount(getState());
  if (currentValue % 2 !== 0) {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }
};
```

My question is Where do I raport the Issue?
thx
Filip

Answer (score 0):

You can log an issue here:

https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux

For finding future maintainers of Create React App templates, search in npm for `cra-template-` + the name... in this case `cra-template-redux`.